# Is there a situation where `console.log` and console.dirxml` behave differently?

Tags: javascript, xml, browser, console, console.log

I've been looking into alternatives on the Console API in JavaScript.
In certain browsers `console.log` prints out things differently to `console.dir`, the biggest difference being with HTML elements.

However I can't find a situation where `console.log` behaves differently to `console.dirxml`. Are there objects I haven't come across that have an XMLrepresentation that `console.log` doesn't use?